# Weird Event Handling

Tags: html, css, web

I made a simple website that contains images of arrows (png) on the left and right with fixed positioned, that link to the next page.
The problem is that the cursor can not select the anchor element that contains the image, as seen in here:

[image: GIF].

Here is the code for the elements:

```
<a class="arrow-left" href="previousPage.php"><img src="img/left.png"></a>
<a class="arrow-right" href="nextPage.php"><img src="img/right.png"></a>
```

As you can see it is plain html code and the `.arrow-left` and `.arrow-right` classes are styled with scss:

```
.arrow-right {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 3%;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 1%;
  top: 50%; }

.arrow-left {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 3%;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 1%;
  top: 50%; }
```

Comment: use display:inline-block in image

Comment: This looks like an issue with hover effects interfering, or something like that. But the few lines of code you have shown hardly reproduce this issue, so please create a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You may try `display: block` on the `.arrow-right` and `.arrow-left`.

*TIP:*
If you'll write your code a more compact way, it will be easier to modify in the future:

```css
.arrow-right,
.arrow-left {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 3%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
}

.arrow-right {
  right: 1%;
}
.arrow-left {
  left: 1%;
}
```

Then you'll have to edit the code on only one place to add `display: block;`